# Thinning of Poisson process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Question: Insects land in the soup in the manner of a Poisson process with intensity $\lambda$. Insects are green with probability p, independent of the color of the other insects. Show that the arrival of green insects is a Poisson process with intensity $\lambda$p.

Im only interested in one step of the solution. Our professor started out calculating the characteristic function of an exponential random variable.

"We solve this by checking that the times, call one such typical time T, between arrivals of new green insects are $exp(p\lambda)$ - distributed"

$$E[e^{j\omega\exp(\lambda)}] = ... = \frac{\lambda}{\lambda - j\omega}$$

Its the next step that is confusing me

$$E[e^{j\omega\exp(T)}] = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{\lambda}{\lambda - j\omega})^n p(1-p)^n$$

What is he doing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He's dividing the event "green insect arrives at time such-and-such" into a disjoint sum of events "green insect arrives at time such-and-such *after exactly $n-1$ non-green insects have arrived*".

Comment: Ok, but what is the nth power of the characteristic function of an exponential doing there?

Comment: @JKnecht: That's because the characteristic function of a sum of independent variables (namely the waiting time between the $n$ insects in each case) is the product of the characteristic functions of the variables.

Comment: +1 Yes, our professor was saying basically the same. And i understand that the independce leads to a product. But is $$\frac{\lambda}{\lambda - j\omega}$$ a waiting time. The characteristic function of an exponential is that a waiting time?

Comment: Does this results hold for a general renewal process? see the problem here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1825150/thinning-a-renewal-process-poisson-generalization